# Fade And Slide About Animation WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, about-box

I have a label with multi-line content.

I want the label's content to slide from the bottom and every line fade when it's turn to visible

Is there any way to do that with `XAML (WPF)` ?

I see this a lot in application's "About" box.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the effect you're after? Having trouble visualizing what you mean by "every line fade when it's turn to visible"

Comment: Like AIMP3's About-Box: http://www.aimp.ru